# Can AMP for Email be used in Marketing Automation tools?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

More specifically has anyone had any experience using AMP with Infusionsoft Emails or Campaigns?

I've asked on slack, searched the documentation, but not tried it yet if it's not even possible. I'm just first looking to see if conceptually that it's even possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer:

- If you are using a third-party software like Infusionsoft or MailerLite, they have to support AMP emails
- If your marketing emails are coming out of your site (via PHP or your server side language) make sure you include a plain text / HTML version of the AMP email for email clients who don't support it.

Comment: Ok great thanks, I am pretty sure they don't support AMP emails, or at least not officially. From glancing at the email help, could what would be the best way to test it  to see. I couldn't find a fully fleshed out sample of code for an AMP email that I could cut and paste. Do you have one, or recommend a space where I can find a sample that I could hack around with to see if I can get it to work?